# en/ language prefix remains after uninstalling internationalization module and dependencies

Tags: 7, uri, i18n-l10n

I have cloned an existing internationalized Drupal website to create a new website. This new website does not need internationalization and translation. Therefore, I uninstalled all corresponding modules.

Unfortunately, the navigation through pages still use the default language prefix `en/`. Drupal complains that it does not find pages anymore. Yet, when I remove the prefix manually from the URL, the pages are reachable again.

How can I have Drupal stop using the `en/` prefix in URLs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the en/ prefix comes from core module **Locale**, you can change the configuration here: `/admin/config/regional`

Comment: I had forgotten to remove locale.